# why writing function of setTimeout separately would not work

Tags: settimeout

I am trying to build 'Simon Game' and used setTimeout method to lighten the buttons. when I write the the functions directly inside the setTimeout method it works.

```
 $(function(){
    var randPattern=[];
    var buttonId=['red','yellow','green','blue'];
    var origColor=['#B40404','#D7DF01','#0B610B','#0B0B61'];
    var patternColor=['#F78181','#F4FA58','#A9BCF5','#81F781'];
    var level= 5;
    var count= 0;
    var time= 1000;



    $('#start').click(function gameStart() {
        patternGenerate();
        for(i=0; i<randPattern.length; i++){
          display(i);
        }


    });

     function patternGenerate() {
         for(var h=0; h<level; h++){
             randPattern.push( Math.floor( Math.random()*4) );

         }
     }
    function display(i){
        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(buttonId[randPattern[i]]).style.backgroundColor = patternColor[randPattern[i]];document.getElementById(randPattern[i]).play();}, 1500*i);
        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(buttonId[randPattern[i]]).style.backgroundColor = origColor[randPattern[i]]}, 750+1500*i );
    }
```

but when I write the functions that is going inside setTimeout method separately, such function a(i), and function b(i). It doesn't work. And the console says ''cannot read the property 'style' of null''. I think there is no difference between these two. I can't understand why the second way doesn't work while the first one does.

```
$(function(){
var randPattern=[];
var buttonId=['red','yellow','green','blue'];
var origColor=['#B40404','#D7DF01','#0B610B','#0B0B61'];
var patternColor=['#F78181','#F4FA58','#A9BCF5','#81F781'];
var level= 5;
var count= 0;
var time= 1000;



    $('#start').click(function gameStart() {
        patternGenerate();
        for(i=0; i<randPattern.length; i++){
          display(i);
        }


    });

     function patternGenerate() {
         for(var h=0; h<level; h++){
             randPattern.push( Math.floor( Math.random()*4) );

         }
     }
     function a (i){
        document.getElementById(buttonId[randPattern[i]]).style.backgroundColor = patternColor[randPattern[i]];
        document.getElementById(randPattern[i]).play();
    }
    function b (i){
        document.getElementById(buttonId[randPattern[i]]).style.backgroundColor = origColor[randPattern[i]];
    }
    function display(i){
        setTimeout(a,1500*i);
        setTimeout(b,750+1500*i);
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `b` expect to be passed an argument which will be assigned to `i`.

While you have a variable called `i` in the `display` function: You aren't passing it to `a` or `b`.

```
function display(i){
    setTimeout( a, 1500*i,     i );
    setTimeout( b, 750+1500*i, i );
}
```

Comment: I wrote the parameters but it still doesn;'t work. It's like the color changes occur almost at the same time.

Comment: Did you call the functions immediately with `a(i)` instead of doing what I showed you in the code in this answer?

Comment: oh I wrote as you said and it worked. It's not allowed to write parameter directly to the function in case of setTimeout?

Comment: `setTimeout(a())` will call `a` **immediately** and pass its return value to `setTimeout` to be executed later.

Comment: so after given amount of time, setTimeout executes not the function a but the return value of function a? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Yes. In your example, `a` has no `return` statement so it returns `undefined`. Since `undefined` is not a function (or, ick, a string to be `eval`ed) nothing happens after the timers runs out.

Answer (score -1):

You are using an `i` inside `function display(i){` but this variable is not passed to `a` or `b`. If you want to pass a variable, you still need to create a new closure and call your function from it:

```
function display(i){
    setTimeout(function() { a(i) }, 1500*i);
    setTimeout(function() { b(i) }, 750+1500*i);
}
```